# Preventing DOMContentLoaded from firing before a cloneInto has happened in a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently working on a firefox addon that adds a function to the DOM.

This function adding works fine:

**lib/main.js**

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["*", "file://*"],
    contentScriptFile: data.url("function_worker.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready'
})
```

**data/function_worker.js**

```
function hello(){
    alert('hello')
}
unsafeWindow.hello = cloneInto(hello, unsafeWindow, {cloneFunctions: true});
```

This is all good and can be access using a button click etc.

However, I want to call this when the page loads, like:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){window.hello();})
```

But I get `TypeError: hello is undefined`. I think this is because the `DOMContentLoaded` listener fires before the `contentScriptWhen:ready` fires.

**How can I suppress `DOMContentLoaded` until after my DOM attribute has been added?**

I understand that I could just request that the page use a timeout of 100 seconds or something to continually check if the attribute is there, but it seems messy and hackish.

Answer (score 0):

You could try seting the `contentScriptWhen` option to 'start', see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#PageMod%28options%29) for page-mod.